# access android application from android browser

Tags: android, android-browser

I just tried to open my android application from my android browser but it is not working. I tried several things but not yet find had any results. In Main Activity I have not coded anything.  Can you give me some suggestions?

I have tried these following set of code:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
             <data
                 android:host="http://urlofsite.com/demo/test/test.html"
                 android:scheme="http" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

I am totally confused with android schema concepts.

This is the code included in my html page:

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <a href="urlofsite">click me!</a> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see you had trouble with your question layout, but I fixed that for you. You cannot put four spaces before the first word in a question, as that is the notation for code. :-)
I have also copied the extra code from your comments. You can include more code in your question by pressing the `edit` button just below it.

Comment: what do you expect to happen, and what does happen (or does not happen)?